# How to write code for speed up manual process

Tags: r

Can someone help me with some tips to create code for my problem? Step by step I am capable of solving some problems but I have no idea how to start with writing loops and my own function to speed up my work. Below, you can see my last problem which is because of small dataset quite easy for me to finish but problem is when I have much bigger dataset (when I need to create 30 and more "diff" columns).

thank you for your time :)

```
id=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
distance=c(43.59304,  152.66197,  208.00968,  272.92662,  380.79429,  
469.62269,  556.72725,734.29125,  796.42570,  873.09448, 1040.64550)
c=data.frame(id,distance)
c
c[paste("diff",1:3, sep="")]=NA 
c$diff1=abs(c[c$id>0,][1,2]-c$distance)
c$diff2=abs(c[c$id>0,][2,2]-c$distance)
c$diff3=abs(c[c$id>0,][3,2]-c$distance)
c
c$min=apply(c[,c(3:5)], 1,FUN=min)
```

edit:

Basically I want calculate shortest distance for each points with ID=0 to the nearest point with ID=1. 
Data "distance" is a distance along line for each points.

[Picture for better understening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPae4.jpg)

Comment: you should explain your specific problem, not expect us to decode it, and never ever name a variable `c` ;)

Comment: to add too @Moody_Mudskipper comment; It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question I will also recommend to take a look at the [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part in the middle could be done by using `outer`, which applies a function (your function, i.e. the absolute difference) to every pair of two input-vectors.

I therefore switch notation, because @Moody_Mudskipper made a good point: never name a variable `c`.

It is by the way often better to refer explicitly to columns by writing their names instead of their column index, just in case your column changes positions.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
                 distance = c(43.59304, 152.66197, 208.00968, 
                              272.92662, 380.79429, 469.62269, 
                              556.72725, 734.29125, 796.4257, 
                              873.09448, 1040.6455)), 
            .Names = c("id", "distance"), 
            row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
            class = "data.frame")

differences <- 
    outer(Y = df[df[["id"]] > 0, "distance"], X = df[, "distance"], FUN = function(x, y){
        abs(x - y)
    })

differences <- as.data.frame(differences)

names(differences) <- paste0("diff", seq_len(ncol(differences)))

differences[["min"]] <- apply(differences, 1, min)

cbind(df, differences)
```

As you can see, this also works for more data, since it is flexible. If your needs are completely different, be more specific and share more information.